# Vahanas of Gods

Tags: puranas, gods, tradition, animals

Why Gods and Goddesses (Devas and Devis) have their own vehicles, mounts or vahanas which comprise various types of animals and birds? Do they have some physical significance?

Comment: I imagine it could have been a tool to honor animals by associating them with Divine forms. Not sure about physical significance.

Answer (score 2):

I think Gods have been assigned their respective animals as vahanas to describe which quality or the ability that they posses. E.g., Surya deva rides on an horse-driven chariot. The qualities of Horse is linked with Surya-deva, i.e., being fast or quick etc., Vishnu has Garuda  as his vehicle because Garuda can fly very high and can get a bigger picture of earth. It can also fly great distances which indicates Vishnu deva travels great distances to maintain the world.

Comment: Good to see a new member. You said "God have been assigned," Who assigned to God? Your answer should be clear. Read this [How to write a good answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, many forms are artistic rendition, hence humans assigned to God. It does sound funny.

Comment: e.g. the Sun on seven horses represents the 7 rays of the Sun in the visible spectrum

Comment: Thanks amit, but what is mean by 7 rays ? Namaste sree charan ji. Thanks for your acceptance. I think bhrama the creator must have assigned all this characteristics and qualities to gods, since gods also been created by bhrama ,  to maintain, and to protect the world , and to keep this world and life running. Pls feel free to correct me anywhere,anytime.Thanks all